# Acceleration of a pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

> The figure above shows a pulley system consisting of 3 masses ($m_1$, $m_2$ and $m_3$), a homogeneous wheel (radius R, mass M) and 2 massless pulleyes which are connected by a massless rope. Mass $m_1$ is sliding on an inclined surface (inclination angle $\alpha$) and mass $m_3$ is sliding on a horizontal surface. Assume that there are no slipping and considered frictionless, and pulley 1 and pulley 2 are massless.
>
> Assuming that $m_1 = m_3 = m$ and $m_2 = M = 2m$, determine the accelerations of the masses $m_1, m_2$ and $m_3$.

I've tried to answer this question with the results:

- acceleration of $m_1 : \ddot{x}_1  = g \sin \alpha_1 - {T_1 \over m}$
- acceleration of $m_2 : \ddot{x}_2  = {T_2 \over m} - g$
- acceleration of $m_3 : \ddot{x}_3  = {T_3 \over m}$

But since $T_1, T_2$ and $T_3$ are not given, my answers are wrong. Anyone can help me? I would highly appreciate it.

Sorry for the bad drawing.

Additional calculations that I've made:

- $m_1\ddot{x}_1 = T_1-m_1g\sin\alpha_1$
- $m_2\ddot{x}_2 = -2T_2+m_2g$
- $m_3\ddot{x}_3 = T_3$
- ${1\over 2}MR^2\ddot{\varphi}=-T_3R+T_2R$
- $\ddot{x}_3 = \ddot{\varphi}R$
- $-\ddot{x}_1+2\ddot{x}_2-\ddot{x}_3 = 0$

Comment: Note that you haven't yet taken into account the mass of the wheel.  $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ are not independent of each other.   See if these comments help move you forward a bit.  Also be aware that this is not a homework help site, so you are likely to get hints and questions directed back at you rather than answers.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for “check my work” problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: To me, this homework-like question 1) asls about a specific physics concept, and 2) shows some effort to work through the problem. Thus, I vote it to leave open.

Comment: @peterh : Yes the Qn shows some effort to work through the problem, but it is not asking a conceptual question. The Qns asked are (1) what to do next and (2) check my answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have all equations, and one is not correct.
The usual assumption in these problems are:

1. There is no friction.
2. Ropes are glued to pulleys.

   - From 1. it follows that $T_1=T_2$
   - You forgot, that  $m_2$ is acted on by $T_2$ twice: ${\ddot{x}_2} = {\frac{2T_2}{m_2} -g}$.
   - $T_3=T_2+N$, where N is force which rotates the big wheel.
   - ${\ddot{\beta}} = {\frac{NR}{I}}$, where $I=MR^2/2$.
   - ${\ddot{\beta}} = {\ddot{x}_3}/R$.

With all these additional equations, you should be able to find all the accelerations. However, pay attention to directions - they depend on your initial choice of signs of $g$ and $T$.

Comment: please check my revision, but I still don't know how to replace the $Ts$. And $m_2= 2m$ that's why the $2s$ canceled

Comment: I don't see in your revision that you have put  $T_1=T_2$.

Comment: Okay, can you check if my calculations are right...   $\ddot{x}_1 = gsin\alpha_1+{\ddot{x}_2\over 2gm_1}$, 
$\ddot{x}_2 = g-{2\over m_2}(m_3\ddot{x}_3-Mg)$, and
$\ddot{x}_3 = {m_3\ddot{x}_3\over Mg}$

Comment: I cannot, this is not homework help site. I can help you with understanding of the problem, but I cannot solve the problem for you. Come on, you have not so much to finish.
In your last revision, you have wrote 6 equations in the end. When you add $T_1=T_2$ there will be seven. And so it happens that you have seven unknowns  - $T_1, T_2, T_3, \ddot{x}_1,  \ddot{x}_2,  \ddot{x}_3$ and  $\ddot{\phi}$. So the solution is near :)

 UPD: in your last comment there is something strange - $\ddot{x}_3$ equation doesn't look good.

Comment: @hello : As explained, this is not a homework help site.  We do not check your answers.

Comment: @Emil Ok, no problem and thanks. But everytime I calculate the acceleration of each mass, they always depend on other acceleration too. Is it okay? or do I have to replace it with something else?

Comment: Last calculation that I've made:  $\ddot{X_3} = 3g-\ddot{X_2};  \ddot{X_2} = g(1-sin\alpha_1)-\ddot{X_1};  and \ddot{X_1} = g(1-sin\alpha_1)-\ddot{X_2}$